# How to redirect current page to other URL depending on current URL?

Tags: redirect

I want to check current url and if it is not home page, i want to redirect that page to particular URL using jQuery or AngularJS

Comment: Can you please add some code that shows what you have already tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Angular]**
  Try following lines of code:

```
       var   location = $location.path();           
        location = location.slice(1, location.indexOf("/"));
        location = location.toLowerCase();


        if (location != 'home') {              
            $location.path('/redirect/somewhere');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need much of jQuery or AngularJS, simple JS is enough.

***location.href*** does the same.

***For Example:***

```
if(location.href != home_page_URL)
     location.href = new_page_URL;
```